# How do I make an animation for when the mouse is hovering the canvas on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i want to make the canvas grow whenever the mouse is hovering it and as soon it leaves the canvas it comes back to normal.

```
toolbar = tk.Canvas(root,height = 840, 
                            width = 50 ,
                                bg= '#9BC4BC', 
                                    borderwidth = 0, 
                                    highlightthickness = 0)
toolbar.pack(anchor = 'nw', 
                before = schedule)

def enter(event,self):
    toolbar.update('840x200')

def exit_(event,self):
    toolbar.update('840x50')

toolbar.bind('<Enter>', enter)
toolbar.bind('<Leave>', exit_)
```

i tried this but it does not work. I'm new to programming so i'd be happy if you guys could help me

Comment: Why do you have the `self` in `exit_(event, self)`? Doesn't it raise an error?

Comment: Also, use `toolbar.config(height=840,width=200)` and `toolbar.config(height=840,width=50)` instead of `update` (`config`/`configure` method is used to change the parameters of a widget)

Comment: yeah now it works,thanks guys! I was testing everything to make the code work, that's why i tried putting 'self' there. thx very much again